# Widget not rebuilding on notifyListeners during test

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-provider, widget-test-flutter

I'm trying to build a Widget test for a screen that's using the Provider framework.

The app has 1 screen with 1 button, when I tap the button it will trigger a function to update the state. Once the state is updated a string with the key `Key('LoadedString')` will appear. 
When manually testing in the simulator this works as expected.

When I'm trying to use a widget test to verify the expected behavior it seems like the UI is not updating.

This is the Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'provider_page_state_controller.dart';

class ProviderPageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ProviderPageStateController>(
          create: (context) => ProviderPageStateController())
    ], child: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    ScreenState state =
        Provider.of<ProviderPageStateController>(context).pageState;

    // Loading state
    if (state == ScreenState.Loading) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Center(child: Text('Loading...')),
      ));
    }
    // SuccessfullyLoaded state
    if (state == ScreenState.SuccessfullyLoaded) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, (screenHeight / 2) - 100,     0, 0),
                  ),
                  Text('Loaded!', key: Key('LoadedString')),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Reset',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize:     20.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Provider.of<ProviderPageStateController>(context,
                                listen: false)
                            .updateState(ScreenState.InitialState);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))));
    }
    // InitialState (=default state)
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, (screenHeight / 2) - 100,     0, 0),
            ),
            Container(
              key: Key('ButtonA'),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Button A',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<ProviderPageStateController>(context,
                          listen: false)
                      .functionA();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ScreenState { InitialState, Loading, SuccessfullyLoaded }

class ProviderPageStateController extends ChangeNotifier {
  var pageState = ScreenState.InitialState;

  void updateState(ScreenState screenState) {
    pageState = screenState;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> functionA() async {
    updateState(ScreenState.Loading);
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      updateState(ScreenState.SuccessfullyLoaded);
    });
  }

  Future<void> reset() async {
    updateState(ScreenState.InitialState);
  }
}
```

This is the Widget test:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider_page/provider_page_state_controller.dart';
import '../provider_page/provider_page_widget.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('ProviderPageWidget SuccessfullyLoaded test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final providerPageStateController = ProviderPageStateController();

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ListenableProvider<ProviderPageStateController>.value(
        value: providerPageStateController,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: ProviderPageWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await providerPageStateController.functionA();
    expect(providerPageStateController.pageState, ScreenState.Loading);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 2));
    expect(
    providerPageStateController.pageState,     ScreenState.SuccessfullyLoaded);

    // Why does this assert fail?
    expect(find.byKey(Key('LoadedString')), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Why is the last `expect` of my Widget test failing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. I was not pumping the correct widget in the widget test.

Updating the widget test to the following solved the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider_page/provider_page_state_controller.dart';
import '../provider_page/provider_page_widget.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('ProviderPageWidget SuccessfullyLoaded test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final providerPageStateController = ProviderPageStateController();

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ListenableProvider<ProviderPageStateController>.value(
        value: providerPageStateController,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await providerPageStateController.functionA();
    expect(providerPageStateController.pageState, ScreenState.Loading);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 2));
    expect(providerPageStateController.pageState, ScreenState.SuccessfullyLoaded);

    // Why does this assert fail?
    expect(find.byKey(Key('LoadedString')), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

The change is on the line:

> home: HomePage(),

Comment: Maybe you should change/remove the question because when someone else is searching for this specific problem, the only information they gain is that you basically just did a typo

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't allow me to delete this question

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Provider.value` constructor, since you are using a variable instead of instantiating an object. And to make sure all dependants are updated eagerly use the the `lazy: false` flag in tests, even when the value is [not accessed](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#exposing-a-value). The resulting changes are:

```dart
void main() {
  final providerPageState = ProviderPageState();

...
      Provider<ProviderPageState>.value(
        value: providerPageState,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: ProviderPageWidget(),
        ),
        lazy: false,
      ),
    );
```

I would also recommend switching to [`ChangeNotifierProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html), when using provider to store states. Make sure your `ProviderPageState` is extending `ChangeNotifier` and implementing the needed methods, as reference you can use the [implementation of `ValueNotifier`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3c521fb980104d7e1b5488fcf9dc8b37fd282be6/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L257).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was already using `ChangeNotifierProvider` so this didn't solve my problem. I've added more information in the original posting.